# How to Set Background Image in Ruby On Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am learning ROR by creating a webpage, but am not able to set a bg image, tried different ways but no luck yet.

Hope someone can help...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did found a solution,

In your CSS:

```
background-image: url(background.jpg);
```

or

```
background-image: url(/assets/background.jpg);
```

In `environments/production.rb`:

## Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

## Compress JavaScripts and CSS

```
config.assets.compress = true
```

## Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

## Generate digests for assets URLs

```
config.assets.digest = true
```